# quoted_printable_decode() replaces wrong strings

Tags: php

I'm running `quoted_printable_decode()` on HTML content that is stored in DB and has a lot of these types of characters `=C5=DD=` etc..

However, I also have this string in the HTML which I did not mean to replace:

`<a href="http://www.site.com?id=b1-xmca-sdis">link</a>`

Since it has `=b` in it, it replaces it as well.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: What are the rules to detect what parts of the data are not encoded?

Answer (score 2):

Encode the `=` as `=3D`, which is the equivalent in Quoted Printable.